# Django 1.5.4: no such table: django_site in admin/

Tags: database, django

pip installed south, and added south to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and ran python manage.py migrate, but when I navigate to localhost:8000/admin, it says

no such table: django_site

Did my migration not run successfully? When I enter the command `python manage.py migrate` it no longer throws any error like before when I didn't have South installed, it just returns.

I am using windows 7 and Pycharms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to run `syncdb` before the first `migrate`:

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py migrate
```

The `django_site` should already exist and it's created when you run [syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)